# -[NSRunningApplication activateWithOptions:] not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsrunningapplication

I'm trying to create a program that will focus a certain application (if it is launched). Here is my code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main() {
  // activate Firefox
  NSArray *apps = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier: @"org.mozilla.firefox"];

  if ([apps count] == 0) {
    printf("no matching app\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (![apps[0] activateWithOptions: NSApplicationActivateAllWindows]) {
    printf("failed to activate\n");
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it prints "failed to activate," and Firefox is not brought into focus. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps modifier to activate. It's work ok.

Additionally activateWithOptions: method has the following note:

> This method will return NO if the application has quit, or **is not a
>   type of application than can be activated**.

Comment: Adding `NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps` worked! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Adrian and comrade, I am having an issue with with this, if the all the windows of the process are minimized, it is not un-minimizing the windows. Is there anyway to unminimize the windows then focus? Here is screencast of my issue, I am making a firefox profile manager - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sR5uf4eR8js